# Print Tab Separated rows of Python Dataframe

Tags: python, string, delimiter

I want to print the following dataframe as tab delimited string

```
sku ids output
 1   a   0.1
 2   b   0.2
 3   d   0.4
```

Output:

```
1     a     0.1
2     b     0.2
3     d     0.4
```

It should be a iterate process and print all the rows.

I have tried str.join() but it is not giving me the output that i am looking for. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apply lambda on each row

```
def applytab(row):
    print('\t'.join(map(str,row.values)))
#print('\t'.join(map(str,df.columns))) # to print the column names if required
df.apply(applytab,axis=1)
```

Output

```
a       0.1     1
b       0.2     2
d       0.4     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to Pandas/Dataframes and my answer can certainly be improved, but one way to achieve your required result is the following:

```
def printDataFrame(df):
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        row = list(df.iloc[i])
        print("\t".join(map(str, row)))


printDataFrame(df)
```

This functions loops through all the rows, then for each row inserts a tap after every element in the row and then prints the row as a string.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric's answer is correct is you only want the values. To also include the index column and column headers, use:

```
def printDataFrame(df, include_column_headers=True):
    if include_column_headers:
        print("\t".join(map(str, [''] + list(df.columns))))
    for indx, row in df.iterrows():
        print("\t".join(map(str, [indx] + row.tolist())))

printDataFrame(df)
```